# Possible to make this event DRY'er, guidance with refactoing

Tags: .net, refactoring

I have a 3 radio buttons that control what state a couple textboxs are in, I am using one event for all 3 buttons but the part that controls the textbox seems like it could be stream lined even more ... there must be a better way to handle this event then what I have

```
Private Sub rdo_SkipBitLockerY_CheckedChanged(sender As RadioButton, e As EventArgs) Handles rdo_SkipBitLockerY.CheckedChanged, rdo_SkipBitLockerN.CheckedChanged, rdo_SkipBitLockerU.CheckedChanged
    Select Case sender.Name
        Case "rdo_SkipBitLockerY"
            txt_BDEDriveLetter.Enabled = True
            txt_BDEDriveSize.Enabled = True
            txt_BDEInstall.Enabled = True
            txt_BDEInstallSuppress.Enabled = True
            txt_BDERecoveryKey.Enabled = True
            txt_TPMOwnerPassword.Enabled = True
            txt_OSDBitLockerStartupKeyDrive.Enabled = True
            txt_OSDBitLockerWaitForEncryption.Enabled = True
            AttributeRDOTable("SkipBitLocker") = "YES"
        Case "rdo_SkipBitLockerN"
            txt_BDEDriveLetter.Enabled = False
            txt_BDEDriveSize.Enabled = False
            txt_BDEInstall.Enabled = False
            txt_BDEInstallSuppress.Enabled = False
            txt_BDERecoveryKey.Enabled = False
            txt_TPMOwnerPassword.Enabled = False
            txt_OSDBitLockerStartupKeyDrive.Enabled = False
            txt_OSDBitLockerWaitForEncryption.Enabled = False
            AttributeRDOTable("SkipBitLocker") = "NO"
        Case Else
            txt_BDEDriveLetter.Enabled = False
            txt_BDEDriveSize.Enabled = False
            txt_BDEInstall.Enabled = False
            txt_BDEInstallSuppress.Enabled = False
            txt_BDERecoveryKey.Enabled = False
            txt_TPMOwnerPassword.Enabled = False
            txt_OSDBitLockerStartupKeyDrive.Enabled = False
            txt_OSDBitLockerWaitForEncryption.Enabled = False
            AttributeRDOTable.Remove("SkipBitLocker")
    End Select
```

What can I do to make this less repetitious ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know .Net platform and I just try to do the way I would do in Java, probably you'll find it useful.

- You could use some default values for your params. Let's say your default value for

> txt_BDEDriveLetter.Enabled
>
> txt_BDEDriveSize.Enabled
>
> txt_BDEInstall.Enabled
>
> txt_BDEInstallSuppress.Enabled
>
> txt_BDERecoveryKey.Enabled
>
> txt_TPMOwnerPassword.Enabled
>
> txt_OSDBitLockerStartupKeyDrive
>
> txt_OSDBitLockerWaitForEncryption

is **FALSE**

- Each case action should contain no more than 1-2 statements.
  That's why if you want to obey this rule you should just make extract method refactoring.
- Do not send to method more information than it needs to know.

Your method don't need to know about *sender* object. Just send the name of sender object.

I would refactor your code as follows(sorry, I don't know .Net, I would try to write per sample):

```
Private Sub rdo_SkipBitLockerY_CheckedChanged(Name As String, e As EventArgs) Handles rdo_SkipBitLockerY.CheckedChanged, rdo_SkipBitLockerN.CheckedChanged, rdo_SkipBitLockerU.CheckedChanged
    Select Case Name
        Case "rdo_SkipBitLockerY"
            doRdoSkipBitLockerY();
        Case "rdo_SkipBitLockerN"
            doRdoSkipBitLockerN()
        Case Else
            doElse();
    End Select

Private void doRdoSkipBitLockerY()
    txt_BDEDriveLetter.Enabled = True
    txt_BDEDriveSize.Enabled = True
    txt_BDEInstall.Enabled = True
    txt_BDEInstallSuppress.Enabled = True
    txt_BDERecoveryKey.Enabled = True
    txt_TPMOwnerPassword.Enabled = True
    txt_OSDBitLockerStartupKeyDrive.Enabled = True
    txt_OSDBitLockerWaitForEncryption.Enabled = True
    AttributeRDOTable("SkipBitLocker") = "YES"
Private void doRdoSkipBitLockerN()
    AttributeRDOTable("SkipBitLocker") = "NO"
Private void doElse()
    AttributeRDOTable.Remove("SkipBitLocker");
```

---

If I wanted to make it OOP-way(in Java) I would extract all 3 case as members of enum and send it as an argument to a common method setVariables()

```
enum MY_CASES{
private boolean txt_BDEDriveLetter;
private boolean txt_BDEDriveSize;
...
MY_CASES(boolean txt_BDEDriveLetter, boolean txt_BDEDriveSize , ..){
this.txt_BDEDriveLetter = txt_BDEDriveLetter;
this.txt_BDEDriveSize = txt_BDEDriveSize;
... 
}

CASE1(true, true, ...), CASE2(false, false, ...), CASE3(false, false, ...), ...
}

private Sub rdo_SkipBitLockerY_CheckedChanged(Name String, e EventArgs)
    setVariables(MY_CASES.valueOf(NAME));

private void setVariables(MY_CASES case){
    this.txt_BDEDriveLetter = case.getTxt_BDEDriveLetter;
    this.txt_BDEDriveSize   = case.getTxt_BDEDriveSize;
    ...
}
```

This version allows you to add other cases without refactoring you rdo_SkipBitLockerY_CheckedChanged method.